# How can I refer a static resource containing js inside javascript on a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources

I have a zipped static resource uploaded in my salesforce org which contains different types of js . I want them to be referred in my script on visualforce page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a static resource in the javascript then use :-

"nope: ['{!$Resource.abc}', '{!$Resource.xyz}']"

where "nope:" is a statement in my javscript.

Or else you can use just "'{!$Resource.abc}'" where ever you want to include your static resource javscript.

Answer (score 6):

You have to include it as you would with any other JS file.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LibraryJS, '/base/subdir/file.js')}"/>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm

Comment: Thanks Sander for the reply , but this script is to be reffred somewhere in the my script which I have written on my page

Comment: Yes, if you include it like this you will be able to refer it from your page.